# iam trying to change content on form with laravel to mysql

Tags: php, laravel, web

this is the blade, where i am trying to change the status from 1 to 2 with onchange method

```
<td>
                    <form method="post" action="/update-status/{{ $cars->id }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        
                        <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1" {{ ($cars->status) == 1 ? 'selected' : null }}>למכירה</option>
                            <option value="2" {{ ($cars->status) == 2 ? 'selected' : null }}>נמכר</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </td>
```

this is the controller

```
public function updateStatus(Request $request,Car $cars)
{
    $cars->update($request->all());
    return redirect('cars-list' );
}
```

this is the route

```
Route::post('/update-status/{cars}', 'HomeController@updateStatus');
```

Comment: Do you want to change status in database while changing the dropdown ??

Comment: yes exactly, any answer?

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to toggle between status 1 & 2, so change your blade code to this

```
<td>
    <form method="post" action="/update-status/{{ $cars->id }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        
        <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="status">
            <option value="1" @if(($cars->status) == 1) selected @endif>למכירה</option>
            <option value="2" @if(($cars->status) == 2) selected @endif>נמכר</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</td>
```

and change your controller to this:

```
public function updateStatus(Request $request,$cars){
    $cars = Cars::find($cars);
    if($cars->status == 1){
        $cars->status = 1;
    }
    else{
        $cars->status = 2;
    }
    $cars->save();

    return redirect('cars-list');
}
```

Let me know if it's helpful

Comment: the if statement should have `$request->status`, not `$cars->status`

Comment: bro, can we chat again? @KhalidKhan